# UINavigationBar background from an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I have an image of width x height = 1 x 44 that I want to transform on the x horizontal for the purpose of generating a background for my nav bar. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this link help:
http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/

"As of iOS 5, Apple has officially added support for setting background images in UINavigationBars. To do this, all you need to do is execute the `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` method of UINavigationBar."

Answer (score 0):

try this in the viewController.m file `viewDidLoad` method

```
for(UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBG.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
[imageView release];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```